# Find the Contact and Account name for an Idea Vote in the UI

Tags: apex, visualforce, configuration, ideas

I am wondering if I am missing something when using the Ideas functionality within SF.  One of the biggest complaints from our product development team is that you cannot tell who actually voted for Ideas.  It shows the username of the person, and when you click on it, it doesn't go to a user record at all, it goes to some internal Zone page where it lists there recent activity, but still gives you no insight to who it is or what account they are a part of.

[image: Idea View]

[image: User View]

I know we can get all this through reports, but they really would like to be able to quickly see this through the UI.

I code code a Visualforce page to show this, but would hate to go through the trouble if there was some setting I was missing.

Can anyone shed some light on this?